# ExtJs 3.4 : Populate combo box from a json store which is in another javascript file

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, combobox

I have a json store in my TourPlan.js file as following.

**TourPlan.js**

```
var driverStore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
storeId: 'driver_store',
fields : [ {
    name : 'dCode'
}, {
    name : 'dName'
} ],
root : 'driver',
autoLoad : true,

proxy : new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
    url : "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/" + projectName + "/"
            + "Driver"

}),
reader : {
    type : 'json',
    root : 'driver'
},
});
```

There is another javascript file called AssignVehicle.js. It has a combo box as following. I want to populate this combo from driverStore.

**AssignVehicle.js**

```
{
    xtype : 'combo',
    name : 'include_type',
    fieldLabel : 'Driver',
    editable : false,
    style : 'marginBottom:6px',
    labelStyle : 'padding-left:65px;',
    store : Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('driver_store'),
    displayField : 'dCode',
    valueField : 'dName',
    //mode : 'local',
    triggerAction : 'all',
    selectOnFocus : true,
    disabled : true
}
```

I've tried

```
store : Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('driver_store'),
```

But it doesn't even show the form.

How should I do this.

Comment: A few quick question, are you sure the store is loaded before the combo?  Is it making a request, and if so is it successfully loaded in the store?

Comment: yeah, is store is loaded before the combo.this works fine sometimes, but most of the time my firebug console says this.store is undefined

Comment: TypeError: this.store is undefined
 

this.store.clearFilter();

Comment: Sometimes the store is loaded before the combo. Then it works fine. But sometimes combo is loaded before the store. Then it gives an error.**TypeError: this.store is undefined
this.store.clearFilter();**

Comment: How should I make sure that the store is loaded before the combo ?

Comment: Is this store going to be reused? if so, I would consider making it a class or a singleton. Otherwise, I would consider putting it inline. If you are talking about synchronization of it, you could use Ext.require if you are using Ext 4.

Answer (score 0):

you can make driverStore as global variable ,then it will available across all js fiels.

eg: instead of

**var driverStore=new Ext.data.JsonStore...**

you can use just

**driverStore =new Ext.data.JsonStore....**

Answer (score 0):

Syntex error at

reader : {
    type : 'json',

> Blockquote

```
root : 'driver'
```

}****,****